# Circular redirect path detected and wrong Open Graph data displayed

Tags: http, facebook-opengraph

When sharing the following URL to Facebook

`www.magicsoftware.com`

You will get outdated information. Facebook refers to the site (magicsoftware.com/en) and takes all the information from the cache.

I tried to clear the cache by going to the dubugger-
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.magicsoftware.com

But that didn't help much.

Someone has an idea what I can do?

---

**P.S** - if you checked the debugger link, you would see that there are two critical errors mentioned:

> Could Not Follow Redirect:    URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could
>   not be followed. Errors That Must Be Fixed
>
> Circular Redirect Path:   Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect
>   Path' section for details).

What does that mean?

Comment: Of course you're not getting any current information. You haven't specified any [OpenGraph metadata](opengraphprotocol.org) from what I have seen of your source. You're at Facebook's mercy about what they choose to display for your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself - and it's only patience :)

Facebook just needs time to remove their cache files. So the solution is simply to use the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to enter your URL and then to wait. Facebook will automatically refresh this URL cache.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but you either lying or just unaware of changes that was done to your server configuration. Your server now returning the page, than previously it was dead-loop redirection if no `Accept-Language` header was passed. There is no need to wait for cache to be cleared if you using debug tool (aka linter), **using it clearing the cache**!

Comment: Man I don't have any reason for lying... :)

Comment: I post this question after I tried using the debugger tool, when I was coming back from the weekend I saw your answer and thought "cool, maybe he's right!" and I wanted to show you exactly what is facebook shows me when I link to the site, but I saw that everything turns ok (and I didn't done nothing except of using the debugger tool on Tuesday).

This the truth man - thanks for you reply any way

Comment: And If you still don't believe me I can show you the log from my linux machine that shows that I didn't done nothing since 19/6 till 24/6

Answer (score 3):

Your server is issuing redirect to the same URL as visited based on some condition, actually according to my tests on any requests that came without `Accept-Language` header get redirected.

See [with `Accept-Language` header](http://hurl.it/hurls/bd5f66c05cf63c2e56730c7aa52fa1b2cdf0fc6f/de8a45477b632541d0aefa41bcc2ca0364f6fc05), and [without any headers](http://hurl.it/hurls/7c89e2d0c21f9c3d7096f6b30b229b4739a2c39d/8593230ff1cc3a2b836fd583c7bc1a50eead8ff2)

Facebook linter doesn't seems to pass this header while crawling your OpenGraph meta and hung due to redirection loop.

You should avoid that redirection (or at least have some fallback) for Facebook linter to be able to collect updated data and update the cached version.

Comment: Thanks for the this answer but I found the solution, and it's patient :)
It's just took facebook time to refresh the cache...

Comment: @OrenRoth, it's not the case, using debug tool purges the cache.

Comment: @JuicyScripter No, it doesn't. You really have to wait. How much, no ANSWER.

Comment: @JuicyScripter is right, debug tool makes an actual hit to your resource and caches the response for the object when it is used on facebook. As far as cache refresh goes without using the debugger facebook rescrapes your url every 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing is happening to me now.  I have no redirect in place.  but I am getting this message " there was an error following the redirect path." when using the debugger on this URL http://www.mmaid.co/cleaning-services/offers/coupons/social-discount.php  I will give it time and see if it fixes itself.

Comment: Your `og:url` value is wrong. It should be `og:url="http://www.mmaid.co/cleaning-services/offers/coupons/social-discount.php"` instead of `og:url="http://www.mmaid.co/cleaning-services/offers/social-discount.php"`